# Prove $\forall x$, $\exists y,z$ s.t. if $z \gt y$ then $z \gt y + x$.

Tags: logic

Prove that for every x, there exist y and z such that if z > y then z > y + x.

Can't you just pick z = 1 and y = 2? That way the condition is always false which means the statement is always true.

My teacher said that you can't do that. In her proof she picked y = -1 and z = x + 1

Comment: Please rewrite your uninformative, un-searchable title.

Comment: the integers, but I don't think it really matters

Comment: Well, ... $1$ and $2$ are not Irrationals.

Comment: well you could pick 1 + pi and 2 + pi. I meant that my method of making z > y false wouldn't depend on the subset that z and y are in

Answer (score 1):

For any $x$, it is *not true* that $1>2$.  Thus for any $x$ it *is true* that $(1>2)\to(1>x+2)$.  (A conditional statement is satisfied whenever the antecedent is unsatisfied.) So, for any $x$ there is some $y$ and some $z$ which satisfy $((z>y)\to(z>x+y))$.

So your witnesses do work.

---

- Nothing is greater than itself.
- Thus we may take any arbitrary $x$ and find some $y$ and some $z$ where $(z>y)$ is unsatisfied. (Witness $y=x$ and $z=x$.)
- A conditional statement is satisfied when ever its antecedent is unsatisfied.
- Therefore: for any $x$, there is some $y$ and some $z$ which satisfy $((z>y)\to(z>y+x))$.

  $\models \forall x~\exists y~\exists z~.((z>y)\to(z>y+x))$

$\blacksquare$